# Is there any way to react to the script-app becoming activate?

Tags: applescript

Is there any form of handler in Applescript to react to the user clicking the dock icon of a compiled applescript that is ALREADY RUNNING? The only thing I can think of is repeatedly checking for the focused app every second but it's a very clunky solution for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible if the script is saved as application. Then the `reopen()` handler is called.